# samba install affecting update and other package installation

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, samba

```
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (67.0.3396.87-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.8.2+dfsg-1) ...
Checking smb.conf
ERROR: Unable to load default file
dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.8.2+dfsg-1); however:
  Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-samba:
 system-config-samba depends on samba; however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-samba (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
samba-common-bin
```

Comment: kindly help resolving this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post to explain: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? Please also include the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, i am experiencing a login loop after my theme update and ubuntu-update

Comment: Again, Could you **please [edit] your post** when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks. Beyond that your problem description appears to diverge completely from the title of your question. Please resolve that conflict.